# Merging $\ n $ number of $\ n\times n $ matrices together to form one

Tags: matrices, statistics, covariance

Assume that a dataset $\ D $ has been (horizontally) divided into $\ n $ subsets and generated $\ n $ number of covariance matrices $\ C1, C2...Cn $ for each subset.

How can I merge  $\ C1, C2...Cn $ to form $\ Cm $ in such a way that $\ Cm = C(D) $, where, $C(D)$ is the covariance matrix of $\ D $

I already tried the method provided in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance), but when the $\ Cm $ is compared with $\ C(D) $, they are totally different.

Comment: What method did not work? How sure are you there is no bug? Also [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262196/combining-2-covariance-matrices).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the method given in the bottom of the wikipedia page. I actually tried the method provided in the page you referred. The values are still different (not large differences though).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on the linked page above, for $n$ sets of data $S_i$, you can compute
$$
C_i = \frac{1}{|S_i|-1}\sum_{s\in S_i}(s-\mu_i)(s-\mu_i)^T
$$
and then use the following estimator
$$
C = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i |S_i|\,C_i
$$
where $N = \sum_i |S_i|$.

Assuming the subpopulations do come from the same distribution, this is an [unbiased estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262196/combining-2-covariance-matrices). 
But note that it should have some variance; i.e. expect some variance compared to the more direct "full" estimate.